# Anyway to debug Quicklink UML Profile in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm trying to create a "Quicklink" document for customizing the allowed connector types between elements. Our UML Profile already exists like below:

[image]

Big version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcKQT.png

And this imports as an MDG Technology just fine.

However, when I add a "Quicklink" document to the profile and import it as an MDG Technology, I get the error "Encountered an improper argument". Those of you familiar with MDG Technologies in Sparx EA knows that there is no logging of any sort as to why it failed. Unfortunately, the documentation is just as unhelpful.

Here is my Quicklink document:

```
//Source Element Type,Source Stereotype Filter,Target Element Type,Target Stereotype Filter,Diagram Filter,New Element Type,New Element Stereotype,New Link Type,New Link Stereotype,New Link Direction,New Link Caption,New Link & Element Caption,Create Link,Create Element,Disallow Self Connector,Exclusive Stereotype Filter + No Inherit from Metatype,Menu Group,Complexity Level,Target Must be Parent,Embed Element,Precedes Separator LEAF,Precedes Separator GROUP,Dummy Column,
Feature,ChiFeature,Requirement,ChiRequirement,,,,Realization,,to,satisfies,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,Requirement,0,,,,,,
```

My question is, is there any way for me to find out why the Quicklink document is invalid. Alternatively, is there someone more experienced with this that can see the issue?

Comment: Open your profile XML file in a text editor and look for the line <QuickLink data="..."/>. Does the text inside the quotes look like your quicklink document quoted above, and if not, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your first question: no, I'm afraid not. As you note, EA is not very user-friendly when it comes to debugging extensions.

Happily, I've spotted the problem: you've got too many columns. Instead of filling in a dummy value at the end you've added an additional comma, which means an extra column. Replace that with a 0 and you should be OK. (Plus, of course, there shouldn't be a comma at the end of the comment line either.)

So try

```
//Source Element Type,Source Stereotype Filter,Target Element Type,Target Stereotype Filter,Diagram Filter,New Element Type,New Element Stereotype,New Link Type,New Link Stereotype,New Link Direction,New Link Caption,New Link & Element Caption,Create Link,Create Element,Disallow Self Connector,Exclusive Stereotype Filter + No Inherit from Metatype,Menu Group,Complexity Level,Target Must be Parent,Embed Element,Precedes Separator LEAF,Precedes Separator GROUP,Dummy Column
Feature,ChiFeature,Requirement,ChiRequirement,,,,Realization,,to,satisfies,,TRUE,,TRUE,TRUE,Requirement,0,,,,,0
```